# Ошибка в программе вычисления суммы ряда на C

Tags: c, циклы

Исходная задача:

> Даны действительные числа  X,E. Вычислить сумму с точностью до E:

[image]

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<math.h>

main(void)                // 
{
                          // 
    int x, n, i;          // i-переменная счетчика цикла
    float s, ch, e, f;    // s-сумма членов сходящегося ряда ch, f-факториал

    printf("nnEnter number X: ");
    scanf("%f", &x);      // Ввод числа X
    printf("nnEnter precision: ");
    scanf("%f", &e);      // Ввод точности расчета

    n = 1;                // Начальное значение аргумента для вычисления члена ряда
    ch = 1;               // Начальное значение члена ряда
    s = 0;                // Присвоение начального значения рекуррентного выражения
                          // накопления суммы
    while (ch > e)        // Цикл выполняется до тех пор, пока очередное значение
    {                     // выражения больше заданной точности
        f = 1;            // Присвоение начального значения рекуррентного выражения
                          // вычисления факториала
        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            f *= i;       // Вычисление факториала
        ch = pow(-1, n) * (pow(x, (2 * n + 1))) / (f * (2 * n + 1)); // Вычисление выражения
        s += ch;          // Накопление суммы
        n++;              // Переход к следующему члену ряда
    }
    printf("Сумма равна s=%f", s); // Вывод полученного значения
                          // суммы на экран
    getch();              // Задержка экрана до нажатия любой клавиши
}
```

Comment: а что не работает то конкретно?

Comment: Если в качестве X взять число 5, к примеру, а в качестве точности указать 1 (то есть считать до 1), то результат выполнения программы следующий

Enter number X: 5 Enter precision: 1 Summ is s=-411438946831628900000000000.000000

Есть где-то ошибка в условии, но не могу понять точно, где. В С не очень силен...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы сделал вот так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <clocale>
using namespace std;
int fact(int k);
double E;
int k = 0;
float Summ = 1, x, F;
void main()
{
    setlocale(0, "Rus");
    cout << "Введите  x" << endl;
    do {
        cin >> x;
        if (x == 0)
            cout << "Ошибка: x = 0, Введите данные заново!" << endl;
    } while (x == 0);
    cout << "Введите Е" << endl;
    do {
        cin >> E;
        if ((E < 0) || (E >= 1))
            cout << "Ошибка, Введите данные заново!" << endl;
    } while ((E < 0) || (E >= 1));
    double f = 1;
    while (true) {
        f *= -x * x * (2 * k + 1) / (2 * k * k + 5 * k + 1); // по признаку Даламбера рассчитан коэффициент на  который отличаются следующий член ряда от предыдущего

        if (fabs(double (f)) < E)
             break;
        else
            Summ += f; // если точность больше чем член ряда, то выход из цикла, иначе накапливаем сумму
        cout << "Локальная сумма: " << f << endl;
        k++;
    }
    cout << "Конечная сумма: " << Summ << " полученная за " << k << " шагов." << endl;
    system("pause");

};
```

Comment: Спасибо за предложенное решение, но нужен вариант на чистом С (не С++)

Comment: Варианты отличается только вводом-выводом

Comment: alexlz, не согласен! Вариант одни решен что называется "в лоб" с кучей не нежных, повторяющихся вычислений: 
      ch = pow(-1, n) * (pow(x, (2 * n + 1))) / (f * (2 * n + 1));
 мой же, с использование признака Даламбера, более компактный и оптимизированный:
      f *= -x * x * (2 * k + 1) / (2 * k * k + 5 * k + 1);

Comment: @Захар Золотарёв Прошу прощения. Выразился сильно неуклюже. Я отвечал на реплику про C/C++, т.е. Ваш вариант для C переписывается заменой ввода-вывода.

Comment: alexlz, ничего страшного, с кем не бывает.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще-то следует поискать "эффект" прежде, чем делать лобовые вычисления

sqr(pi) * erf(x)/2

где erf(x) - интеграл ошибок. Задача свелась к его нахождению с заданной точностью.